# Undefined Qt5 references in C++ using CMake (mingw) in Windows with CLion

Tags: c++, windows, qt, clion

I am trying to [learn Qt5 with CMake](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) in the new [CLion C/C++ IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/), I am relatively new with these tools. So, I have this *real simple* code `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QDebug>
int main() {
    qDebug("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

I've followed the documentation and ended with this `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
project(cl_hello_world2)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH D:/Qt/Qt5.4.0/5.4/msvc2012_opengl)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

find_package(Qt5Widgets)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(cl_hello_world2 WIN32 ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(cl_hello_world2 Qt5::Widgets)
```

After hours and hours of trying, I keep having these `undefined reference` errors:

```
CMakeFiles\cl_hello_world2.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
E:/Qt/test/cl-hello-world2/main.cpp:4: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK14QMessageLogger5debugEPKcz'
```

This is the compiler command that CMake is executing:

```
D:\PROGRA~2\CODEBL~1\MinGW\bin\G__~1.EXE   -std=c++11 -g    -mwindows -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\cl_hello_world2.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o cl_hello_world2.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcl_hello_world2.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  D:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\lib\Qt5Widgetsd.lib D:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\lib\Qt5Guid.lib D:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\lib\Qt5Cored.lib D:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\lib\qtmaind.lib -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

I don't know if this line is syntactically correct, but the library `D:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\lib\Qt5Widgetsd.lib` exists...

I've try with Qt5.3.2 and Qt 5.4.0. Maybe you know some other way to add the library for the linking or maybe I've made a mistake...

Thanks.

Comment: You can not use visual studio binaries for mingw. Use a mingw build of Qt.

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't notice that... I will look for that mingw build of Qt

Comment: @drescherjm please add your comment as an answer and I will accept it... maybe I will add some edits to your answer to clarify some problems that I had. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is you are attempting to use a Visual Studio build of Qt with mingw. You need to use a mingw build of Qt.

**Edit**

1. If you are going to use MinGW, download the right Qt Version at http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/ *Qt 5.4.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.9.1, 852 MB)*. At the moment of installation don't forget to select MinGW 4.9.1 component.
2. Follow this step if you are going to use CLion: In File : Settings or Ctrl + Alt + S, choose the correct path of MinGW as shown:

[image: CLion toolchain configuration]

3. In *CMakeLists.txt* change the line:
   `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH D:/Qt/Qt5.4.0/5.4/msvc2012_opengl)` for where your Qt path is: `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH D:/Qt/Qt5.4.0MinGw/5.4/mingw491_32)`
4. Now if you compile and run from the IDE you will get the error: `Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)`. You need the Qt libraries in your path or in the directory where your exe is. I had to copy `icudt53.dll icuin53.dll icuuc53.dll libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll libstdc++-6.dll libwinpthread-1.dll Qt5Cored.dll Qt5Guid.dll Qt5Widgetsd.dll` in my directory (the "d" is for "debug").
5. If you run this [sample code for Qt beginners](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_for_beginners_Hello_World) from CLion you will get this!

[image: Running Qt MinGW and CMake from CLion]

About my initial code I do not understand what is happening but I can't figure it out why qDebug doesn't print in stdout...

Comment: for clarification: qDebug doesn't print in stdout because this is not a console applicattion, see `add_executable(cl_hello_world2 WIN32 ${SOURCE_FILES})` the *WIN32* label is defined for non-console applications